Converting pigpio code to Gpiod library python
I have the following code of pigpio library and I have to convert it's functionality using gpiod library. Where pigpio has a good documentation I can understand the working of previous code using that. But the problem arises when I try to convert it, the gpiod does not have a documentation at all (or I couldn't find one).
The following is the code of pigpio
import pigpio

relay_1 = 5
pi = pigpio.pi()
def setupGPIO():
    if not pi.connected:  # Check connected
        print("Not connected to PIGPIO Daemon")
        setupGPIO()
    else:
        print("Connected to PIGPIO Daemon")

        pi.set_pull_up_down(relay_1, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
        cb1 = pi.callback(relay_1, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, pinChange)

def pinChange(pin, state, t):
    if (state == 0):
        print('LOW', pin, str(t))
    else:
        print('HIGH', pin, str(t))
    lastPin = t # used somewhere else

    if (pin == interCom):
        some_func(state) 
    else:
        check_lights()


def check_lights(self):
    r1 = pi.read(relay_1)
    totals = r1
    print(f'totals != pinTotals {totals} {pinTotals}') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setupGPIO()

What I was able to achieve
import gpiod

relay_1 = 5  
def setupGPIO(self):
    print('setup gpio initiated')

    try:
        config = {
            relay_1: gpiod.LineSettings(
                direction=gpiod.line.Direction.INPUT,
                bias=gpiod.line.Bias.PULL_DOWN
            )
        }

        with gpiod.request_lines(
            "/dev/gpiochip4",
            consumer='gpio-setup',
            config=config
        ) as request:
            print('Connected to GPIO')

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to setup GPIO: {e}')
        setupGPIO()

    print('setup gpio executed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setupGPIO()

Do not know the correctness of this code but I did this and tested for blink test that was mentioned in one example.
If any one can help me convert this code that would be great, or if any one can guide me or provide some documentation that would really help. Thanks for any help in advance

I am converting because the pigpio lacks the support for Pi5. The code not that hard too understand anyone having basic knowledge of modules can understand.

So why are you asking? The replacement for pigpio is lgpio and reasonably well documented, which can not be said of gpiod. Both require a fundamentally different approach to coding. Neither of your code samples appear to be a complete executable.

Not exactly sure what your code is trying to achieve, but I'll assume you are wanting to monitor the state of a pin.
There are some examples of common use cases in the gpiod source.  Of those, the watch_line_value.py example is probably the closest to what you are after.
And you can generate the gpiod docs locally with python -m pydoc -p 1234 and pointing your browser at http://localhost:1234/gpiod.html.
